# Reflector code from byte array C#

Tags: c#, arrays, reflector

I have received a byte array of an object form from server and can use it by the following code:

```
 Form form = (Form)Activator.CreateInstance(Assembly.Load(Byte_Array_From_Server).GetType(AssemblyTypeOfForm));
```

How can i read the source code of that form in reflector, i've already tried to write byte array to text file but i cannot see.